# Raku Cro service subscribing to data "in the background" general guidance

Tags: raku, cro

I am attempting to put together a Cro service that has a react/whenever block consuming data "in the background" So unlike many examples of websocket usage with Cro, this has nothing to do with routes that may be accessed via the browser.

My use case is to consume message received via an MQTT topic and do some processing with them. At a later stage in development I might create a supply out of this data, but for now, when data is received it will be stored in a variable and dependant on certain conditions, be sent to another service via a http post.

My thought was to include a `provider()` in the `Cro::HTTP::Server` setup like so:

```
use Cro::HTTP::Log::File;
use Cro::HTTP::Server;

use Routes;
use DataProvider; # Here

my Cro::Service $http = Cro::HTTP::Server.new(
        http => <1.1>,
        host => ...,
        port => ...,
        application => [routes(), provider()], # Made this into an array of subs?
        after => [
            Cro::HTTP::Log::File.new(logs => $*OUT, errors => $*ERR)
        ]
    );
```

And in the DataProvider.pm6:

```
use MQTT::Client;

sub provider() is export {
    my $mqtt  = MQTT::Client.new: server => 'localhost';
    react {
        whenever $mqtt.subscribe('some/mqtt/topic') {
            say "+ topic: { .<topic> } => { .<message>.decode("utf8-c8") }";
        }
    }
}
```

This throws a bunch of errors:

```
A react block:
  in sub provider at DataProvider.pm6 (DataProvider) line 5
  in block <unit> at service.p6 line 26

Died because of the exception:
    Invocant of method 'write' must be an object instance of type
    'IO::Socket::Async', not a type object of type 'IO::Socket::Async'.  Did
    you forget a '.new'?
      in method subscribe at /home/cam/raku/share/perl6/site/sources/42C762836A951A1C11586214B78AD34262EC465F (MQTT::Client) line 133
      in sub provider at DataProvider.pm6 (DataProvider) line 6
      in block <unit> at service.p6 line 26
```

To be perfectly honest, I am totally guessing that this is how I would approach the need to subscribe to data in the background of a Cro service, but I was not able to find any information on what might be considered the recommended approach.

Initially I had my react/whenever block in the main `service.pm6` file, but that did not seem right. And needed to be wrapped in a `start{}` block because as I have just learned, react is blocking :) and cro was not able to actually start.

But following the pattern of how Routes are implemented seemed logical, but I am missing something. The error speaks about setting up a new method, but I'm not convinced that is the root cause. `Routes.pm6` does not have a constructor.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: That's something going on in $mqtt. Might be a bug... It should instantiate the class, instead of using class methods.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But the approach I am taking is sound @jjmerelo?

Comment: looks fine to me, but I would have to download and check it...

Comment: It's not immediately clear that you need to be making a Cro service at all. from what you described, it seems like the MQTT react is the "main loop" of your program, then you'd use Cro::HTTP::Client to send HTTP requests. If you don't need to serve HTTP, Cro::HTTP::Server isn't needed.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington As it stands that's true, and I initially thought I would not have a full blown Cro server. But I will at a later stage require this server to have some endpoints of it's own, including an endpoint for monitoring. And having the odd html template populated with data and updating via websockets to the client would be very useful. So I figured I'd go with my aspirational state architecture from the start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be fine now but when I first saw this I made this https://github.com/jonathanstowe/Cro-MQTT which turns the MQTT client into a first class Cro service.

I haven't released it yet but it may be instructive.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to all who have provided information, this has been a very valuable learning exercise.

The approach of passing additional sub routines, along side `router()` in the `application` parameter to `Cro::HTTP::Server.new` gave further trouble. (an array is not allowed, and broke routing)

Instead, I have moved the background work into a class of it's own, and given it a `start` and `stop` method more akin to `Cro::HTTP::Server`.

My new approach:

service.pm6

```
use Cro::HTTP::Log::File;
use Cro::HTTP::Server;

use Routes;
use KlineDataSubscriber; # Moved mqtt functionality here 
use Database;

my $dsn         = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=act user=.. password=..";
my $dbh         = Database.new :$dsn;

my $mqtt-host   = 'localhost';
my $subscriber  = KlineDataSubscriber.new :$mqtt-host;

$subscriber.start; # Inspired by $http.start below

my Cro::Service $http = Cro::HTTP::Server.new(
    http => <1.1>,
    host => ...,
    port => ...,
    application => routes($dbh), # Basically back the way it was originally 
    after => [
        Cro::HTTP::Log::File.new(logs => $*OUT, errors => $*ERR)
    ]
);

$http.start;
say "Listening at...";
react {
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Shutting down...";
        $subscriber.stop;
        $http.stop;
        done;
    }
}
```

And in KlineDataSubscriber.pm6

```
use MQTT::Client;

class KlineDataSubscriber {
    has Str $.mqtt-host is required;
    has MQTT::Client $.mqtt = Nil;

    submethod TWEAK() {
        $!mqtt = MQTT::Client.new: server => $!mqtt-host;
        await $!mqtt.connect;
    }

    method start(Str $topic = 'act/feed/exchange/binance/kline-closed/+/json') {
        start {
            react {
                whenever $!mqtt.subscribe($topic) {
                    say "+ topic: { .<topic> } => { .<message>.decode("utf8-c8") }";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    method stop() {
        # TODO Figure how to unsubscribe and cleanup nicely
    }
}
```

This feels much more "Cro idiomatic" to me, but I would be happy to be corrected.
More importantly, it works as expected and I feel is somewhat future proof. I should be able to create a supply to make real-time data available to the router, and push data to any connected web clients.

I also intend to have a http GET endpoint `/status` with various checks to ensure everything healthy

Answer (score 7):

## The root cause

> The error speaks about setting up a `new` method, but I'm not convinced that is the root cause.

It's not about *setting up* a new method. It's about a value that should be defined instead being undefined. That typically means a failure to attempt to initialize it, which typically means a failure to *call* `.new`.

> Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Hopefully this question helps.

## Finding information on a recommended approach

> I am totally guessing that this is how I would approach the need to subscribe to data in the background of a Cro service, but I was not able to find any information on what might be considered the recommended approach.

It might be helpful for you to list which of the get-up-to-speed steps you've followed from [Getting started with Cro](https://cro.services/docs/intro/getstarted), including the basics but also the "Learn about" steps at the end.

## The error message

```
A react block:
  in sub provider ...

Died because of the exception:
    ... 
      in method subscribe ...
```

The error message begins with the built in `react` construct reporting that it caught an exception (and handled it by throwing its own exception in response). A ["backtrace"](https://docs.raku.org/type/Backtrace) corresponding to where the `react` appeared in your code is provided indented from the initial "A react block:".

The error message continues with the `react` construct summarizing its own exception (`Died because ...`) and explains itself by reporting the *original* exception, further indented, in subsequent lines. This includes *another* backtrace, this time one corresponding to the original exception, which will likely have occurred on a different thread with a different callstack.

(All of Raku's structured multithreading constructs<sup>**[1]**</sup> use this two part error reporting approach for exceptions they catch and handle by throwing another exception.)

---

The first backtrace indicates the `react` line:

```
in sub provider at DataProvider.pm6 (DataProvider) line 5
```

```
use MQTT::Client;

sub provider() is export {
    my $mqtt  = MQTT::Client.new: server => 'localhost';
    react {
```

---

The second backtrace is about the original exception:

```
    Invocant of method 'write' must be an object instance of type
    'IO::Socket::Async', not a type object of type 'IO::Socket::Async'. ...
      in method subscribe at ... (MQTT::Client) line 133
```

This reports that the `write` method called on line 133 of `MQTT::Client` requires its [invocant](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Invocant) is an *instance* of type 'IO::Socket::Async'. The value it got *was* of that type but was *not* an instance, but instead a ["type object"](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#index-entry-Type_objects). (All values of non-native types are *either* type objects *or* instances of their type.).

The error message concludes with:

```
  Did you forget a '.new'?
```

This is a succinct hint based on the reality that 99 times out of a hundred the reason a type object is encountered when an instance is required is that code has failed to initialize a variable. (One of the things type objects are used for is to serve the role of "undefined" in languages like Perl.)

So, can you see why something that should have been an initialized instance of 'IO::Socket::Async' is instead an uninitialized one?

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> Raku's constructs for parallelism, concurrency, and asynchrony follow the *structured programming* paradigm. See [Parallelism, Concurrency, and Asynchrony in Raku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpqnNCx7wVY) for Jonathan Worthington's video presentation of this overall approach. Structured constructs like `react` can cleanly observe, contain, and manage events that occur anywhere within their execution scope, including errors such as error exceptions, even if they happen on other threads.

Comment: Thanks @raiph for such a detailed troubleshooting guide. The code for the MQTT client I am using is a module: https://github.com/Juerd/p6-mqtt/blob/master/lib/MQTT/Client.pm#L133 However the real problem was that I had not called connect (see my answer below) Unfortunately the approach of passing additional sub routines in the http server application also did not work with a type constraint error: Type check failed in binding to parameter '$application'; expected Cro::Transform but got Array ([Bool::True, Cro::HT...)

Comment: "the real problem was that I had not called connect " The error message precisely nailed the problem. Line 133 is `$!connection.write ...`. The declaration of `$!connection` is `has IO::Socket::Async $!connection;`. The error message was "Invocant of method 'write' must be an object instance of type 'IO::Socket::Async', not a type object of type 'IO::Socket::Async'.". I wrote at the end of my explanation of the error message, "So, can you see why something that should have been an initialized instance of 'IO::Socket::Async' is instead an uninitialized one?". Yes! You hadn't called connect. :)